# Meaning of dx and dy in MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to simulate mouse clicks for my opencv project in C++. I am using `mouse_event()`, and I do not understand the meaning of the `dx` and `dy` parameters when sending `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` events.

Are the terms "absolute" and "relative" used in documentation related to screen or cursor?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes,I read the documentation.But,I had some doubts about the usage

Comment: The `mouse_event()` documentation is very clear on what those parameters are and how they are used.  Why do you think it is not clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dx` and `dy` parameters can refer to either absolute or relative coordinates.

If you don't want the mouse to move, set them both to `0` and make sure you **don't** set the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag (that is; you need to use relative coordinates, since adding `0` to the existing position results in no change).

Also note that `mouse_event` is deprecated; you should be using [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.